# Connect and search in database not array

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am trying to implement search function in my web application, what I am trying to do is search for a word in database and if it does not exist system should tell me or find me the closest match to the word.I want to search in database for name not search in array Following is my `index.php`

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="two.php">
Search :  =<input type="text" name="name" id="x" autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</html>
```

this is my `two.php` code

```
<?php
$input = $_POST[name];
$words  = array('apple','pineapple','banana','orange',
                'radish','anything','carrot','pea','bean','potato');
$shortest = -1;
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if ($input == $word) {
        $closest = $word;
        $shortest = 0;
        break;
    }
    $lev = levenshtein($input, $word);
    if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
        $closest  = $word;
        $shortest = $lev;
    }
}
echo "Input word: $input\n";
if ($shortest == 0) {
    echo "Exact match found: $closest\n";
} else {
    echo "Did you mean: $closest?\n";
}
?>
```

and this is the structure for my database i search in for name

```
create database search 
create table emp ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(30) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`));
```

Comment: then what is the problem?

Comment: @jogesh_pi  i want to search in database for name not in array

Comment: Connect the database, send the `$_POST[name]` into the select query, and the thinking part for you is the closest word.

Comment: i try to do it but couldn't solve the problem for now @jogesh_pi

Comment: where is your tried code? i can't find it here? You should show us your tried code and the error you get.